# How can i refer to a class which is present next to the div

Tags: jquery

when clicked on a Class , i am trying to achieve toggle functionality this way

But could anybody please let me know how can i refer to the class os-description in this case

**This is my HTML**

```
<div class="order-listdetails-wrap" id="1950">
   <div class="orderTitle">Popcorn Regular
   <i class="icon-os-description" id="itemdesc1950" data-description="This is Best Popcorn in Market" ></i>
   </div>
   <div class="os-description" id="desc1950" style="display: none;">Ravi</div>
</div>

$(document).on("click", ".icon-os-description", function() {
    var data_description = $(this).attr("data-description");
    var dest = $(this).next('os-description');
    dest.html( data_description ).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To refer to the div after the click, just select its [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and then the [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element, like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".icon-os-description", function() {
    var div = $(this).parent().next(".os-description");
});
```